# no such file to load -- readline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error:

```
$script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.2.2)
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20080709/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/completion.rb:10:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
```

Where can i get the file and what directory should it go in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The readline module is normally part of the Ruby package itself.

Did you manually build your Ruby install? If so, you want to make sure libreadline and its headers are installed, and build again.

On Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

Or on RHEL/CentOS, try

```
yum install readline-devel
```

**Update:**

You are using a very old release of Ubuntu. If you want to keep using it, open `/etc/apt/sources.list` in a text editor, and change all occurrences of `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. Then, run `apt-get update` and try the above again.

I urge you to consider updating your installation, though. Ubuntu 7.10 hasn't seen security updates in quite a while, and using it in production is not recommended. Even if it's not a production machine, there's a good chance you'll run into further problems because of old versions of certain libraries/dependencies.

Comment: on "apt-get install libreadline-dev" get the following error: Err http://archive.ubuntu.com gutsy/main libncurses5-dev 5.6+20070716-1ubuntu3
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.45 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libncurses5-dev_5.6+20070716-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.45 80]

Comment: @Shteef i am using CentOS release 5.6 and had sample problem.So I have tried yum install readline-devel as root.but still i am getting same problem.do you have any idea friend? and Ruby path is /usr/local/bin/ruby

Comment: If it's in `/usr/local`, I guess you built it manually? After installing readline-devel, you need to build ruby again.

Answer (score 31):

You need to install the ncurses and readline libraries.

On Ubunutu you could do

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline5-dev libncurses5-dev
```

and then you will have to recompile readline which comes with your ruby source

```
cd <ruby-src-dir>/ext/readline
ruby extconf.rb
make
sudo make install
```

If you are using RVM you could simply do

```
rvm package install readline
```

EDIT:

On newer RVM versions, this last command is

```
rvm pkg install readline
```

Comment: On "sudo apt-get install libreadline5-dev libncurses5-dev" getting: Err http://archive.ubuntu.com gutsy/main libncurses5-dev 5.6+20070716-1ubuntu3
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.40 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libncurses5                 -dev_5.6+20070716-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.40 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Exemplary answer: concise, clear, and covers several different set-ups. I think this should be set as the answer to this question!

Answer (score 10):

Add the following line to your Gemfile and run `bundle update`

```
gem 'rb-readline'
```

credits to similar question/answer at [install ruby 1.9.3 using rvm on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920574/install-ruby-1-9-3-using-rvm-on-ubuntu)

Comment: This worked for me as well with a little adjustment: when using rails 4, in the Gemfile set `gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.4.2'`

Answer (score 6):

This easiest way to get relief from this problem,
just add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rb-readline'
```

And then run `bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

Run the command

```
rvm requirements
```

It shows the requirements and dependencies. Install those and reinstall the ruby on rvm

```
rvm remove 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.2
```

It works!

**EDIT**

If you can't find the `requirements` option update your rvm.

```
rvm update --head  # older rvm
```

or use `rvm upgrade`

Comment: Thanks, Sayuj. I tried the command and got "ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'requirements' ( see: 'rvm usage' )". I ran 'rvm usage' and did not see requirements anywhere in the result. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Jay: Try `rvm -h`. You should get `requirements - Shows additional OS specific dependencies/requirementes for building various rubies.`

Comment: what is the result of `rvm -v`

Comment: @Jay: You may be using old rvm. Try reinstall rvm. https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is a bullshit answer, but I ran into this problem today after upgrading postgres from 9.5.3 to 9.6, along with which homebrew upgraded readline from 6.something to 7. I ended up rolling back my postgres to 9.5.3 and that resolved the issue.