# how to install "readline" for rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, readline

ok i am trying to run "rails console" command but here's what i get:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/completion.rb:10:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/completion.rb:10
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:37:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:37
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

how can I install "readline" and make it work ?

Comment: Use google first -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385549/no-such-file-to-load-readline

Answer (score 12):

I know it is too late.

no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)

try adding `gem ’rb-readline’` to your Gemfile.)

Answer (score 6):

**rvm package** has been changed to **rvm pkg**

It would be nice if the error just told us this! Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ rvm uninstall 1.8.7
$ rvm package install readline
$ rvm install 1.8.7 -C –with-readline-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/hoanga/2009/09/08/getting-ruby-191p243-to-work-on-os-x-1058-with-japanese-input-support-on-irb/

Comment: when i run "rvm package install readline" i get this "ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'package' ( see: 'rvm usage' )"