# Rails console is not working - rails c

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've reinstalled the Ruby version a bunch of times, but I couldn't find why, when I go to the terminal and type `rails c`, it throws this error:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
from /Users/cleytonmessias/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/cleytonmessias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@trustvox/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/cleytonmessias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@trustvox/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/cleytonmessias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@trustvox/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:51:in `require'
from /Users/cleytonmessias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@trustvox/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:51:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm on Mac OSX Mavericks, Ruby-2.0.0-p247 and Rails 4.

Comment: Have you run `bundle`?  Are you in a rails application's directory?  It seems like you don't have libreadline or the readline gem.  [Several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270169/how-to-install-readline-for-rails-console?rq=1) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385549/no-such-file-to-load-readline) identical.

Comment: Yes...I'm on my application directory. Does libreadline only to Ubuntu? Im on Mavericks

Comment: This one was answered here already:   
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6375913/1870446

Comment: @Chelios This only works for Ubuntu. I'm on Mavericks

Comment: Please do `rvm uninstall ruby-2.0.0-p247`. Then run `rvm requirements`, if there are anything pending to be installed, install it. After that do a fresh `rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247`.

Comment: You didn't compile ruby with readline support.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a reference that helped me.

Using this [link](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X):

- brew install readline
- brew link readline
- I went to file `~/.rvm/user/db` and add the following line: `ruby_configure_flags=--with-readline-dir=/usr/local/opt/readline`
- rvm reinstall 2.0.0-p247 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local

Now when I type `rails c` it's working again :)