# rails console is not working in rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on a rails application which uses rails 3.2.1. i created a separate gem set for it and installed gems. till now every thing worked fine but when i go to rails console i am getting the following error:

```
/home/santosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rbin require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
from /home/santosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in'
from /home/santosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@sample/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rbin require'
from /home/santosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@sample/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in'
from /home/santosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@sample/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in require'
from /home/santosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@sample/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in'
from script/railsin require'
from script/rails:6:in'
```

browsed through google and tried installing readline but no use. so where am i doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385549/no-such-file-to-load-readline perhaps this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem due to the ruby installation with rvm.

To fix this, I uninstalled my ruby version and I intalled it with this command :

```
rvm install 1.9.2 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/.rvm/usr
```

I hope it helps