# rails console require cannot load such file readline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and I install ruby by source.

Ruby version is 2.3.0 and rails version is Rails 4.2.5.

I can't run `rails c` or `rails console`.

It giving me the following error:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 4267
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:58:in `console'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/james/Desktop/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

**EDIT**

I try second solution in @Vasfed link, and it give me following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/internal.h', needed by `readline.o'.  Stop.
```

Comment: try `spring stop` and than `rails c`

Comment: i tried, but still running via Spring preloader.  Btw, what is Spring?

Comment: so remove it from `Gemfile` than in console `bundle` than `rails c`

Comment: Are you using a ruby built with readline? try `require 'readline'` in `irb`

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385549/no-such-file-to-load-readline

Comment: I already install  `libreadline-dev`.  I try reinstall  `spring`,too. Still the same error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Readline gem is required by your application but not specified in your Gemfile

Please add this to your gem file

```
gem 'rb-readline'
```

Also reinstall

```
libreadline-dev
```

Comment: try removing the ruby version and reinstalling it and then do the above steps.I hope it works because it will recreate ruby dependencies

Answer (score 1):

If you installed from source, install libredline-dev first and then go to ruby-2.3.0/ext/readline (or wherever the source code is)/ext/readline.

`ruby extconf.rb`

`make`

`make install`

if you get an error, edit `Makefile` after runing extconf.rb and add `top_srcdir = ../..` after `archdir = $(rubyarchdir)`.

Then, run `make && make install` again.

Answer (score 1):

You need some extra dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl libcurl3 libreadline-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libffi-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev
```

After installing dependences, do this in ruby source code folder:

```
.configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer (installing the gem rb-readline) is a workaround.

Don't do that, instead, your ruby should be installed with ext/readline.

For that you need ncurses devel and readline devel libraries

In CentOS that is

```
yum install readline readline-devel ncurses ncurses-devel
```

For Ubuntu, read Abel's anwer.

Oh, and after installing the libraries, you should recompile your ruby.